# Is $\frac{\sin(z^{\alpha})}{z^{\alpha}}$ entire?

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Let $f(z) = \frac{\sin(z^{\alpha})}{z^{\alpha}}$ for $\alpha > 1$ and $z \in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. Then $f$ is holomorphic (if a recall correctly ...) My question is: is $f$ holomorphic at $z = 0$ ? Can we use Riemann continuation theorem (because $\lim_{z\to0} f(z) = 1$) to say that $f$ can be analytically continued in $0$ hence forming an entire function?

I have calculated $$f'(z) = \frac{\cos(z^{\alpha})\alpha z^{\alpha-1}}{z^{\alpha}}  -\alpha \frac{\sin(z^{\alpha})}{z^{\alpha+1}} = \alpha \left( \frac{\cos(z^\alpha)- \frac{\sin(z^\alpha)}{z^{\alpha}}}{z}\right)$$ We are interested in $\lim_{z\to 0} f'(z)$. Using L'Hospital rule we obtain, that if $\exists \lim_{z\to 0}f'(z)$ then
$$ \lim_{z\to 0} f'(z) = \lim_{z\to 0}\alpha \left(\sin(z^{\alpha})\alpha z^{\alpha-1} - f'(z)\right) = \lim_{z\to 0} -\alpha f'(z)$$ hence, if exists then $f'(0) = 0$. Is it correct? How to calculate $f''(0)$ ?

Comment: I assume $\alpha$ is supposed to be an integer?

Comment: I intend $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ with $\alpha > 1$ Is it ok? Some holomorphic branches of logarithm are involved then?

Comment: It's not clear to me that that is even _continuous_ on all of $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ when $\alpha$ is a non-integer.

Comment: In general, to define $z \mapsto z^{\alpha}$ we make a choice of branch cut of $\log$ and declare $z^{\alpha} := \exp(\alpha \log z)$. If $\alpha$ is a half-integer $\frac{k}{2}$, then we can make a choice that makes $f$ entire: Indeed, its Maclaurin expansion is then $f(z) \sim 1 - \frac{1}{6} z^k + \frac{1}{120} z^{2 k} - \cdots$. For other $\alpha$ there is no choice of branch for which $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @Travis Therefore $f$ is entire if $\alpha = \frac{k}{2}$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ ? Where can I read more about this?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ih the hypotesis that $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}$ is $f$ entire?

Comment: It depends on what exactly you mean by "this". The topic of branch cuts should be handled in basically introductory grad text on complex analysis (I learned it from Gamelin, which is a good if occasionally dense text). One way to think of this particular situation is as follows: The function $w \mapsto\frac{\sin w}{w}$ is entire and even, so for a choice $\sqrt\cdot$ of branch cut of the square root function as above, $\zeta\mapsto\frac{\sin\sqrt\zeta}{\sqrt\zeta}$ is entire. And, of course, composing with the entire function $z\mapsto z^k$, $k$ a nonnegative integer, give an entire function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\alpha$ is an *integer* $\ge 1$, then yes,
$$f(z) = \begin{cases} \frac{\sin(z^\alpha)}{z^\alpha} & z\ne 0 \\ 1 & z=0 \end{cases} $$
is entire.

You can simply plug $z^\alpha$ into the power series for $\sin$ and divide out $z^\alpha$ term by term -- this gives a power series that must converge at every $z$, because the series for $\sin w$ converges for every $w$, in particular when $w$ happens to be $z^\alpha$.

---

If $\alpha$ is not an integer, then you need to make a branch cut to define $z^\alpha$. And it will generally not be the case that when you approach that branch cut along two different branches, the values of $\sin(w)/w$ will match up between them. So the function can't even be continuous on $\mathbb C\setminus 0$ then.

(Except, as @Wojowu notes, when $\alpha$ is a half-integer, because then the two branches of $z^{\alpha}$ are each other's negatives, and $\sin(w)/w$ happens to be an even function. Alternatively, in that case, plugging $z^\alpha$ into the power series and dividing, the choice of branch cancels out term by term.)

Comment: Thank you for your time!

Comment: $f(z) = \frac{sin(z)}{z}$ is entire $g(z) = z^k$ is entire then $f(g(z))$ is also entire ... right?

Comment: It's also entire at positive half-integers.

Comment: @CMarius: Yes, that's another way to make more or less the same argument. I was assuming you didn't already know $\sin(z)/z$ was entire.

Comment: @Wojowu: Good point, edited in.